# Stray commas when importing CSV into R

Tags: r

I have a large CSV file (170k rows), which I'm importing into R. Each entry in the file is comma-delimited - however, in some of the columns (particularly those with a collection of URLs stuck together), there are commas in the strings. An example below:

```
Will Smith,25/09/68,null,male,08/10/14,450109,TRUE,http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Will_Smith_2011,_2.jpg?width=300http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Will_Smith_2011,_2.jpg/200px-Will_Smith_2011,_2.jpghttp:.....
```

The added comma has a knock-on effect - it makes R (and Excel) think that it is a separate column, which then extends out over other columns and destroying the formatting. Given that there are roughly ~10% of the data affected, is there a quick way to get around this?

Comment: If there are commas in the data, it should have been saved as tab-delimited text.

Comment: If you can't regenerate the file but the commas are at the end then assuming n fields just replace the first n-1 commas with some character not appearing in the file.  Here we will use semicolons: `L <- readLines("myfile.csv"); for(i in 2:n) L <- sub(",", ";", L); read.table(text = L, header = TRUE, sep = ";")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the rule suggested by this limited example is to remove the commas that appear before underscores, then this succeeds:

```
gsub("[,][_]", "_", s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without some rule for when commas should be ignored, no.

If you have some consistant rule then use `str_replace_all` with regex to find the exceptions.

If you're the one making the csv I'd suggest you delimit with a different character.